# Unable to Authenticate User in Laravel PHP with SQLite Database

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, authentication, authorization

I have a simple login and I have been unable to find the error for 2 days now. I have the required login and password in the database, but no matter what I enter in the login, I am thrown out and it says that the login or password is incorrect.
Im using sqllite laravel-10 php
AuthController

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view("auth.login");
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            "email" => ["required", "email", "string"],
            "password" => ["required"]
        ]);

        if(auth("web")->attempt($data)) {
            return redirect(route("home"));
        }
        return redirect(route("login"))->withErrors(["email" => "wrong data"]);
    }


    public function logout()
    {
        auth("web")->logout();

        return redirect(route("login"));
    }
}
```

config/auth.php

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
    ],
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/login', [AuthController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login');
Route::post('/login_process', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login_process');
```

App/Models/User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'name',
        'role',
        'status',
        'password',
    ];
}
```

When I enter the correct data from the database, it just gives an error that the data is incorrect.
i alse add admin user to the db

```
       DB::table('users')->insert([
        'email' => 'admin@example.com',
        'name' => 'admin',
        'role' => 'admin',
        'password' => 'admin',
    ]);
```

i tried to find answers and use different auth methods but nothig works

Comment: You have a syntax error here, unless this happened while pasting ... `["email" => wrong data"]`

Comment: error when pasting. Fixed

Comment: Ensure that the sqlite file is not open by another application. What are you using to view it?

Comment: Database tool in phpstorm

Comment: This statement `if(auth("web")->attempt($data)) {` appears to always return false. Begin your debugging here. By "debugging" you'll have to log the state. You can do this by outputting whichever state to an external file.

Comment: That is true. It is always false and I think mistake somewhere in configuration because I just used very simple authorization

Comment: To clarify, to log the state, do something like `file_put_contents("somefile.txt", print_r($data,true),  FILE_APPEND);` anywhere before the redirect (but outside the false branch). In this way you can view the state before continuing to the next stage of debugging.

Comment: Also turn on error reporting and enable PHP logging. This will allow you to see errors that your own custom logging (above comment) doesnt have.

Comment: I forgot to tell you. With the help of logs I realised that the same thing is in data as in DB. Like I output $data in the logs and output the contents of the database. They're the same.

Answer (score -1):

I created a user with

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    'email' => 'admin@example.com',
    'name' => 'admin',
    'role' => 'admin',
    'password' => 'admin',
]);
```

but it didn't work. But then I changed password to

```
'password' => bcrypt('admin'),
```

and this worked